# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{{(n+1)}^{n^2}}{e^n ×n^{n^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate
> $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{{(n+1)}^{n^2}}{e^n ×n^{n^2}}.$$

Ok so I'm pretty sure limit is 1 since we can write this as $(\frac{n+1}{n})^{n^2}$ divided by $e^n$ and since limit of  $(\frac{n+1}{n})^n$ is $e$, we have $e^n/e^n$ so limit is 1.

Is my reasoning here correct?

Comment: Avoid replacing a part of the expresion by its limit unless the part is a term or a factor of the expression. In case of the part being a factor its limit should be non zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea has an error (but I will say you explained it so clearly that it's easy to provide assistance!).

You've correctly reasoned that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{((n+1)/n)^n}e = 1$. From this you want to conclude that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg( \frac{((n+1)/n)^n}e \bigg)^n = 1$. But this is a $1^\infty$ indeterminate form, meaning that the answer doesn't have to be $1$—it could be any nonnegative real number or $\infty$. (For a parallel example, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg( 1+\frac Cn \bigg) = 1$, but that doesn't imply that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg( 1+\frac Cn \bigg)^n$ also equals $1$—indeed, you know it equals $e^C$.)

As with any $1^\infty$ indeterminate form, the best approach is to take logarithms and find the limit of the logarithm of the sequence, then exponentiate at the end. (The very form of this original sequence also suggests that logarithms are a good way to untangle its components.) You will end up needing to know something a little more precise than $\log(1+\frac1n) \sim \frac1n$, maybe something like $\log(1+\frac1n) \sim \frac1n - \frac1{2n^2}$.... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks,  that makes sense

Answer (score 4):

Use that $x-x^{2}/2\leq\log(1+x)\leq x-x^{2}/2+x^{3}/3$ for small $x>0$, we get
\begin{align*}
-\dfrac{1}{2}\leq n^{2}\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)-n\leq-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{n},
\end{align*}
the limit is then $e^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually was able to solve this without using approximation formulas:

Take the logarithm of $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{{(n+1)}^{n^2}}{e^n ×n^{n^2}}.$$
because $\lim \ln x = \ln (\lim x)$.  Now we have
$$\ln\Big[\frac{(n+1)^{n^2}}{e^n\cdot n^{n^2}}\Big] = \ln (n+1)^{n^2} - \ln e^n - \ln n^{n^2}$$ which gives
$$\ln\Big[\frac{(n+1)^{n^2}}{e^n\cdot n^{n^2}}\Big] = n^2\ln (n+1) - n \ln e - n^2\ln n = n^2\big[\ln (n+1) - \ln n\big] - n$$

$$ = n^2 \ln \frac{n+1}{n} -n $$
which will lead to an indeterminate form $\infty\cdot0$, so instead we rearrange for L'Hopital's rule:

$$ = \frac{\ln (1+ 1/n) - 1/n}{1/n^2}$$ and
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln (1+ 1/n) - 1/n}{1/n^2} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{1+1/n}\cdot(-1/n^2) + 1/n^2}{-2/n^3}$$

$$ = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{-n}{1+1/n}+n\frac{1+1/n}{1+1/n}}{-2} = \lim_{n\to \infty} -\frac{1}{2}\frac{-n+n+1}{1+1/n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} -\frac{1/2}{1+1/n} = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Thanks to user284331 for pointing out an error in an earlier version.

Comment: No no, the last one would be like $1-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.